# Finding example file maeswrapdefinitions in Maeswrap package R

Tags: r

I am attempting to run the fortran model MAESTRA using the wrapper function package [Maeswrap](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/Maeswrap/index.html) developed by Remko Duursma for R. The functions work fine, except that a definition file is needed to interface with the model executable using the function `maesparunall()`. According to the help page of the function, an example is included with the package. Indeed, `maeswrapdefinitions` appears in the help index of the package and in the documentation with the description "Example Maeswrap definition file", but no actual example is given there.

I am not sure how to access the example file. There appears to be no function called`maeswrapdefinitions` accessible from the terminal, so I am at a loss.  Any help is much appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The file is available from the Github repository in the data folder: https://github.com/RemkoDuursma/Maeswrap/blob/master/data/maeswrapdefinitions.txt